# Need a way to systematically handle errors/exceptions/rejections in a NodeJS project

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling, exception

#### Background Info

I have a new project I'm working on that will provide multiple different (optional) packages that can be installed, all of which are in addition to the **core** package (only manual package). The other packages just interact with the core.

The project is just meant to keep track of lists of data (not very specific, I know, but these details aren't needed). The add-on packages determine HOW the lists of data are interacted with. The **core** package just consists of all the main JS functionality and database models, and authentication. The other packages tie into those.

- Lets say you want to just have it as a standard web page, you can install the **webui** package, which will tie into the **core**, and create a web app for it
- If you want to create an API, you can install the **restapi** package, which creates the RESTful interface; You can also install the **spaui** package which will interact with the RESTful interface, which gets the data from the **core**

These addon packages I will call "facade" packages. All you really need to extrapolate from the above is that the **core** is a separate package from the *facade* packages, and it handles the *core* functionality (Database stuff, authentication, authorization, etc)

#### Problem

The **core** can use promises or callbacks, and it returns exceptions for failures, then whatever facade package is used to interact with the **core** will handle the exceptions/errors (showing an HTTP error page, returning a RESTful error result, etc).

Since the package that handles the errors is different than the package that returns the errors, there needs to be a systematic way of knowing what *type* of error was returned, so it can be dealt with properly (EG: The webui/restui packages should know if it needs to show a HTTP 500, a HTTP 403, HTTP 409, etc). Obviously of the core just returns `new Error('Something broke')`, then the facade packages don't really know what type of error it is, unless they have the text saved somewhere and can match it up with an error code.

#### Question

Whats the best way to handle this? I haven't been able to find anything that accomplishes this exactly how I want..

I eventually started working on my own attempt.. (below)

#### My *Possible* Solution (If this is sufficient, just confirm)

I created a new `AppError` exception type, and instead of returning `AppError` exceptions with simple strings, you provide an error *code* which will associate that exception with the error message, error type, etc.

Here is an example usage of the `AppError` exception:

```js
exports.createThing = ( name, data ) => {
    return new Promise( ( res, rej ) => {
        if( doesItExist( name ) )
            return rej( new AppError( 'document.create.duplicateName' ) )

        // Other stuff...
    })
}
```

Now inside the `AppError` exception method, it takes the `code` and looks inside a list of exceptions (the `code` should be the key inside an object of exception data).

Heres an example of what the exception data object for the above exception would contain:

```js
module.exports = {
    'document.create.duplicateName': {
        type: 'DocumentConflict',
        message: 'Failed to create new document',
        detail: 'The document name specified already exists, try another one'
    }
}
```

**Example Usage**: Lets say we try to execute `createThing` with an already existing `name` (From within the `webui` package):

```js
CorePackage.createThing( 'foobar', 'some data' )
    .catch( err => {
        /*
        The err is now an instance of AppError

        err.type -> DocumentConflict
        err.message -> Failed to create new document
        err.detail -> The document name specified already exists, try another one
        */
    })
```

From here, it's as simple as associating the `err.type` value with a suitable HTTP error code! (which would probably be HTTP 409 Conflict). Obviously these associations can be kept in an object, making it easy to just retrieve the correct error code for any of the error `type` values returned. Then the text for the error code is right there in `err.message` and `err.detail`

This also makes it easy to introduce some type of locale into the application, as the error, as all that needs to be done is to edit the exception data object.

#### End of post

So if you think my solution above is a sufficient one, and you cant think of any problems, then please say so. Id like to know if it is or if it isn't. Even if you can't think of a proper solution, but you just know the one I created wont work, share that as well.

If you have an alternative solution, then that would work just as well!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think there are two basic ways to approach this:

- **`code` property**: Create a new `\Error` object and assign the code property with information about the error. For example:

  ```
  var err = new Error('Message');
  err.code = "DocumentConflict";
  ```
- **Custom error objects**. You could have a seperate Error object per error type that you have. For example, rather than having just `AppError`, you can have `DocumentConflict` error.

For projects where I am creating a RESTful API, I like to think in terms of error codes. For most projects, the endpoints will return one of the following codes:

- 400 (Bad Request)
- 401 (Credentials Error)
- 403 (Forbidden)
- 404 (Not Found).
- 500 (Internal Server Error).

These then become 'standard' types of Error that I pass around the application. A normal `Error` object is interpretated as an internal server error, so this will always pass 500 to the endpoint.

For example,

```
CredentialsError = function (message) {
  Error.call(this, arguments);
  Error.captureStackTrace(this, this.constructor);
  this.message = message;
};

util.inherits(CredentialsError, Error);
CredentialsError.prototype.name = "CredentialsError";
```

And then just return/throw a `new CredentialsError("Invalid password")` object as necessary. To check the type of object, you can use `instanceof`. With Express, for example, you can have an error handler similar to the following:

```
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  var status;

  if (err instanceof error.FieldError) {
    status = 400;
  } else if (err instanceof error.CredentialsError) {
    status = 401;
  /* etc */
  } else {
    status = 500;
  }

  if (status !== 500) {
    res.status(status).send(JSON.stringify(
      err,
      null,
      4
    ));
  } else {
    // for 500, do not output the error!
    console.error(err.stack);
    res.status(500).send({
      message: "Internal Server Error"
    });
  }
});
```

It is also worth noting that you can defined your custom error object constructors to take more than just strings. For example, you can pass objects into a `BadRequestError` constructor to provide field-level error detail.

Now, in most cases, you can just propagate the errors and the response to the endpoint will make sense. However, there are cases where you want to transmute the type of error. For example, if you have a login endpoint, you might do a request to `findUserByEmailAddress()`. This could return a NotFoundError object, but you want to capture this in the `signIn()` function and transmute it to a CredentialsError.

Comment: I dont really want a lot of different error objects, so I like the first approach (adding the `code` item), which looks fairly similar to my fix, Do you see any important or fundamental differences between the logic in your examples and the logic in my proposed solution? I didn't include *how* I would handle the specific error codes returned, rather just how to return them, but its exactly how you do it. I think the only diff between yours and mine, is mine stores the exception data in an object, which gets referenced, making it easier to manage (IMO), and introduces locale (if ever needed)

Comment: @Justin I think the key difference is that you are using a single AppError object for multiple types of error. However, in the approach I have given, I have used inheritance to have separate error objects for different types of error. There's not a great deal of practical difference. Personally, I don't deal with localisation in the error message itself; I typically deal with that in the presentational logic that reads a code. (In your example, in addition to `message`, I'd have `i18nKey` which will be passed into `i18next` or similar).